# Deploying app to testers using Travis CI and TestFairy

Tags: xcode, travis-ci

I want to deploy an app to beta testers via email. I am using Travis CI and TestFairy but I'm having trouble understanding what to put in the `.travis.yml` file:

```
deploy:
   provider: testfairy // easy enough
   api-key: "TESTFAIRY API KEY" // easy enough
   app-file: Path to the app file (APK/IPA) // what to put here?
```

What should I put under `app-file`? I have a basic Xcode workspace (using CocoaPods) and I'm not exactly sure about where my IPA is. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for TestFairy.

You can always define in your xcode project where you want xcode to output the IPA by editing either the xcode preferences or the project preferences (`Xcode Menu-> Preferences-> Locations` or `Xcode Menu-> File-> Project Settings`).

Then use the path defined by those parameters to give the path to the IPA

Comment: Hey Vijay, thanks for helping out! I'm sorry, but the path defined in the placed you suggested is relative to my computer (not the project path). What I mean is that the paths are all outside the project and I can't edit them. Please check the screenshots I have attached here for reference: https://imgur.com/a/0x1gSwV

Comment: I've found this which may be helpful https://medium.com/@atsakiridis/continuous-deployment-for-ios-using-travis-ci-55dcea342d9

Comment: Hi @Cesare, you can always define project relative paths in those settings. However, you can also override any `xcodebuild` parameters in your .travis file. E.g. you can use `DSTROOT="$(PWD)/build/"` at the end of your `xcodebuild` command, and the output of the IPA should be in a path inside that directory. hope that helps.